# Convert scanned pdf to pdf with text and images

Tags: pdf, ocr

Is it possible to convert scanned pdf to an normal pdf (i.e. same pdf as if it was created from a document (with formatted text and images)) ?

I tried many OCR solutions online/offline
but they tend to loose formatting and/or images

the best one i found was [ocrmypdf](https://github.com/jbarlow83/OCRmyPDF)
but it puts the OCR text over the scanned pdf

Comment: try `print to pdf`

Comment: @jstola that was the first thing i tried ( of course it didn't work )

Comment: what does `it didn't work` actually mean?

Comment: it just OCR the text over old pdf you can see it by the difference in size with "normal" pdf

Comment: You do realize that a document is scanned entirely as an image. From that point on it would take a really good OCR program to decipher, convert and separate the text from the image and reassemble it into a newly created PDF like a word processor. There are some programs that do that, however you'll have to pay for those types of Applications.